# POSTGRESQL PG/PGSQL- Function with params

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I'm having some issues making a function in Postgresql, I have this function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.isp_ticket(_cr integer, _grupo character varying(255), _numero integer, _descripcion text, _resumen character varying(255), _fechaaper timestamp with time zone, _fechacierr timestamp with time zone, _tipo smallint, _apellidousuarioafectado character varying(255), _apellidosolicitante character varying(255), _tenant character varying(255), _metodoreportado character varying(100), _prioridad smallint, _sla character varying(255), _categoria character varying(255), _estado character varying(255), _herramienta_id integer, _asignado character varying(255), _nombresolicitante character varying(255), _nombreusuarioafectado character varying(255))
RETURNS void AS $$

BEGIN
     CASE 
         WHEN _asignado = '' AND _close_date = '' AND _sla = '' 
         THEN  INSERT INTO public.website_ticket(cr, grupo, numero, descripcion, resumen, fechaaper, tipo, apellidousuarioafectado, apellidosolicitante, tenant, metodoreportado, prioridad, categoria, estado, herramienta_id, nombresolicitante, nombreusuarioafectado) VALUES (_cr, _grupo, _numero, _descripcion, _resumen, _fechaaper, _tipo, _apellidousuarioafectado, _apellidosolicitante, _tenant, _metodoreportado, _prioridad, _categoria, estado, _herramienta_id, _nombresolicitante, _nombreusuarioafectado);
         WHEN _asignado = '' AND _close_date = ''
         THEN INSERT INTO public.website_ticket(cr, grupo, numero, descripcion, resumen, fechaaper, tipo, apellidousuarioafectado, apellidosolicitante, tenant, metodoreportado, prioridad, sla, categoria, estado, herramienta_id, nombresolicitante, nombreusuarioafectado) VALUES (_cr, _grupo, _numero, _descripcion, _resumen, _fechaaper, _tipo, _apellidousuarioafectado, _apellidosolicitante, _tenant, _metodoreportado, _prioridad, _sla, _categoria, _estado, _herramienta_id, _nombresolicitante, _nombreusuarioafectado);
         WHEN new_close_date = ''
         THEN INSERT INTO public.website_ticket(cr, grupo, numero, descripcion, resumen, fechaaper, tipo, apellidousuarioafectado, apellidosolicitante, tenant, metodoreportado, prioridad, sla, categoria, estado, herramienta_id, asignado,nombresolicitante, nombreusuarioafectado)
    VALUES (_cr, _grupo, _numero, _descripcion, _resumen, _fechaaper, _tipo, _apellidousuarioafectado, _apellidosolicitante, _tenant, _metodoreportado, _prioridad, _sla, _categoria, _estado, _herramienta_id, _asignado, _nombresolicitante, _nombreusuarioafectado);
ELSE
UPDATE public.website_ticket SET fechacierr = _fechacierr WHERE numero = _numero;
END CASE;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

and when I try to use the function doing this:

```
SELECT public.isp_ticket(924266, 
'EUS_Zona V Region', 
512294,
'Nombre: Gisselle Espinoza Contreras\nCorreo: gespinoza@bancoripley.cl   
\nAnexo: 6221\nUbicación: Valparaiso\nPais: Chile\nMotivo: Usuario indica 
que su computador se apagó repentinamente. Se pudo entrar a windows después 
de un buen rato, pero no puede ingresar a las aplicaciones que se conecten a 
red.\n\nDirección: Plaza Victoria 1646 - Piso 1 - Banco',
'Valparaiso // Computador con problemas de conexión.',
'2018-01-23 15:17:51',
'',
1,
'Espinoza Contreras',
'Espinoza Contreras',
'Ripley',
'Telephone',
3,
'',
'Ripley.Hardware.Desktop.Falla',
'Open',
1,
'',
'Gissel Rose Marie',
'Gissel Rose Marie')
```

I tried to CAST every value, and it didn't work either, always appear the same error:

ERROR:  no existe la función public.isp_ticket(integer, character varying, integer, text, character varying, timestamp with time zone, unknown, integer, character varying, character varying, character varying, character varying, integer, unknown, character varying, character varying, integer, unknown, character varying, character varying)
LINE 1: SELECT public.isp_ticket(
               ^
SQL state: 42883
Character: 8

I need help how can I fix it?

Forwards thanks everyone!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parameter #7, `_fechacierr` should be `timestamp with time zone`. You can not pass `''`, change it to null (and cast it to `timestamp with time zone`) if you need empty value.

And it's worth to read [how PostgreSQL finds specific function to call](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/typeconv-func.html), especially:

> If any input arguments are unknown, check the type categories accepted
>   at those argument positions by the remaining candidates. At each
>   position, select the string category if any candidate accepts that
>   category. (This bias towards string is appropriate since an
>   unknown-type literal looks like a string.) Otherwise, if all the
>   remaining candidates accept the same type category, select that
>   category; otherwise fail because the correct choice cannot be deduced
>   without more clues. Now discard candidates that do not accept the
>   selected type category. Furthermore, if any candidate accepts a
>   preferred type in that category, discard candidates that accept
>   non-preferred types for that argument. Keep all candidates if none
>   survive these tests. If only one candidate remains, use it; else
>   continue to the next step.

Comment: it didn't work.... I delete _fechcierr value and CAST every value and it didn't work either... here is my code, and how I'm calling http://rextester.com/LWOTK18211

Comment: Also cast parameters #7 & #12 to `smallint` and it will work. I got `42P01: relation "public.website_ticket" does not exist` ;)

Comment: I'm having this error 
SQL state: 42883 
ERROR:  no exists function public.isp_ticket(integer, character varying, integer, text, character varying, timestamp with time zone, integer, character varying, character varying, character varying, character varying, smallint, character varying, character varying, character varying, integer, character varying, character varying, character varying)
LINE 1: SELECT public.isp_ticket(

Comment: See your forked query: http://rextester.com/LUQC87866 - I have only changed 2 lines and added casting to `smallint`. Those changes are marked in the comment.